# How to set the tab button to select the whole text in ALL the WinForms NumericUpDown in C#

Tags: c#, select, text, tabs, numericupdown

**My Requirement:**

When someone presses the TAB button and moves to a NumericUpDown control in my form, the whole text of this to be selected, i searched a lot and i found this:

```
private void numericUpDown1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        numericUpDown1.Select(0, numericUpDown1.ToString().Length);
    }
```

I need some code that will do the job for ALL of them because my form has about 50 NumericUpDown controls
I tried something like this:

```
private void System.Windows.Forms.NumericUpDown_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.NumericUpDown.Select(0, 2);
    }
```

but two errors appeared:

`Error 2    An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Windows.Forms.UpDownBase.Select(int, int)'    P:\myWork\C#\sudoku\sudoku\Form1.cs 42  13  sudoku`

`Error  1   The modifier 'public' is not valid for this item    P:\myWork\C#\sudoku\sudoku\Form1.cs 40  21  sudoku`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access the instance of your `NumericUpDown` control being passed to the event through the `sender` parameter. Try this: *(untested)*

(Also, remove `System.Windows.Forms` from the beginning of the event name.)

```
private void NumericUpDown_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var numUpDownControl = sender as System.Windows.Forms.NumericUpDown;

    if (numUpDownControl != null)
        numUpDownControl.Select(0, 2);
}
```

If you want to select the entire value in the control (and not just the first two numbers), change the `Select` statement accordingly:

```
        numUpDownControl.Select(0, numUpDownControl.Value.ToString().Length);
```